# Is this place going to be another form of meta.se?

Tags: discussion

I find myself asking questions regarding the ettiquite of editing, close votes, etc for Stack Exchange, which is already ontopic at each of the stack exchange's metas, as well as on meta.stackexchange itself.

This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but I thought I'd mention it.

Are questions pertaining to the ettiquite/dynamics of participating on SE on topic here? Or is it better to put them on the metas?